# Как создать папку из BAT скрипта с текущей датой в формате yyyy-mm-dd?

Tags: windows, bat

Мне нужно, чтобы BAT скрипт мог создать папку с именем включающим текущую дату.

Интернет полон решений, большинство которых зависит от локальных настроек системы, например :

```
 mkdir %date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~7,2%
```

Мне же нужно создавать папку стабильно и независимо от локальных настроек.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашел вот такой рабочий вариант:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime  ^| find "."') do set dt=%%a
set datestamp=%dt:~0,8%
set timestamp=%dt:~8,6%
set YYYY=%dt:~0,4%
set MM=%dt:~4,2%
set DD=%dt:~6,2%
set HH=%dt:~8,2%
set Min=%dt:~10,2%
set Sec=%dt:~12,2%

set stamp=%YYYY%-%MM%-%DD%_%HH%-%Min%-%Sec%
echo stamp: "%stamp%"
echo datestamp: "%datestamp%"
echo timestamp: "%timestamp%"

mkdir "%YYYY%-%MM%-%DD%"
```

Соответсвенно, можно составлять имя из частей как угодно.